# Map Key value to create a json structure with nested objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, mapping

I want to create an Object of array from the flat array which i will be getting from the query results and want to create json structure as a response to pass it as api response.
For eg-
Flat array-

```
[{
    user_id: '2311123',
    user_country: 'United States',
    user_city: 'ny',
    ssn: 229
  },
  {
    user_id: '451313',
    user_country: 'United States',
    user_city: 'abc',
    ssn: 147
  },
  {
    user_id: '65345',
    user_country: 'United States',
    user_city: 'abc',
    ssn: 444
  },
  {
     user_id: '763343',
    user_country: 'Australia',
    user_city: 'auus',
    ssn: 678
  }]
```

I want to create a structure like- Expected Output

```
{
  "United States": [
    {
      "ny": [
        {
          "user_id": "2311123",
          "ssn": "7"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "abc": [
        {
          "user_id": "451313",
          "ssn": "147"
        },
        {
          "user_id": "65345",
          "ssn": "444"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Australia": [
    {
      "auus": [
        {
          "user_id": "763343",
          "ssn": "678"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

which has user_country array of objects and user_city array of objects mapped.
I have tried this code, but coudnt achieve the expected output.:

```
  const map = {};
  results.forEach(arr => {
   console.log("arr",arr)
        if(map[arr.user_country]){
          if(!map[arr.user_country].includes(arr.user_city))
            map[arr.user_country].push(arr.user_city);
        }else{
          map[arr.user_country] = [arr.user_city]
        }
  });
  console.log(map);
```

Comment: Any reason you need cities to be objects in an array rather than properties of an object? `United States: { ny: [], abc: [] }`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could produce expected results:

```js
const array = [{ user_id: '2311123', user_country: 'United States', user_city: 'ny', ssn: 229 }, { user_id: '451313', user_country: 'United States', user_city: 'abc', ssn: 147 }, { user_id: '65345', user_country: 'United States', user_city: 'abc', ssn: 444 }, { user_id: '763343', user_country: 'Australia', user_city: 'auus', ssn: 678 }];


const map = array.reduce((map, {user_country, user_city, ...userInfo}) => {
  if (!map[user_country]) {
    map[user_country] = [{[user_city]: [{...userInfo}]}];
  } else {
    const ex = map[user_country].find(city => Object.keys(city)[0] === user_city);
    if (!ex) {
      map[user_country].push({[user_city]: [{...userInfo}]});
    } else {
      Object.values(ex)[0].push({...userInfo});
    }
  }
  return map;
}, {});

console.log(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this solution:

```
const map = {};
results.forEach(arr => {
    const { user_country, user_id, user_city, ssn } = arr;
    if (!map[user_country]) {
        map[user_country] = [];
    }

    if (map[user_country][user_city]) {
        map[user_country][user_city].push({user_id, ssn});
    } else {
        map[user_country][user_city] = [{user_id, ssn}];
    }
});

console.log(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const results = [{
    user_id: '2311123',
    user_country: 'United States',
    user_city: 'ny',
    ssn: 229
  },
  {
    user_id: '451313',
    user_country: 'United States',
    user_city: 'abc',
    ssn: 147
  },
  {
    user_id: '65345',
    user_country: 'United States',
    user_city: 'abc',
    ssn: 444
  },
  {
    user_id: '763343',
    user_country: 'Australia',
    user_city: 'auus',
    ssn: 678
  }
]

const out = {};
results.forEach(i => {
  out[i.user_country] = out[i.user_country] || {};
  out[i.user_country][i.user_city] = out[i.user_country][i.user_city] || [];
  out[i.user_country][i.user_city].push({
    user_id: i.user_id,
    ssn: i.ssn
  })
})

console.log(out)
```

Comment: Not the output the OP was looking for which is why I added that comment. But this makes more sense as output fwiw. PS don't forget to coerce the ssn to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that option:

```js
const results = [{
    user_id: '2311123',
    user_country: 'United States',
    user_city: 'ny',
    ssn: 229
  },
  {
    user_id: '451313',
    user_country: 'United States',
    user_city: 'abc',
    ssn: 147
  },
  {
    user_id: '65345',
    user_country: 'United States',
    user_city: 'abc',
    ssn: 444
  },
  {
     user_id: '763343',
    user_country: 'Australia',
    user_city: 'auus',
    ssn: 678
  }];

const countries = {};

results.forEach(result => {
  const {user_country, user_city, user_id, ssn} = result;
  const cityList = countries[user_country] && countries[user_country][user_city] ? countries[user_country][user_city] : [];
  const newCityList = [...cityList, {
      user_id,
      ssn
    }];
  countries[user_country] = {
    ...countries[user_country],
    [user_city]: newCityList
  };
});

console.log(countries);
```